# Predict/Identify country codes for phone numbers

Tags: java, android, phone-number, libphonenumber, mobile-country-code

I have list of mobile phone numbers from different countries from Android contacts. Some of these contacts have country codes while some of them don't.

**So, a solution could be:**

1. Get all supported country codes of the world
2. Loop a number with all the country codes
3. Check validity of number

This could be one way to predict a number for supported countries. I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: I’d be surprised if that was possible. I would expect that the same number could fit as a phone number in many countries.

Comment: You are right, but I believe there maybe some spectrum definition that could be different in each country. e.g. 0176, 0179 ... is in Germany and similar differentiations could in other countries could lead to identify the country code for such numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

String numberStr = "04157012311";
Set<String> allRegions = phoneUtil.getSupportedRegions();
Set<String> validRegions = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

for (String region : allRegions) {
  try {
    if (phoneUtil.isValid(phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, region))) {
      validRegions.add(region);
    }        
  } catch (NumberParseException e) {
    // Handle NumberParseException
  }
}
```

`validRegions` will contain ISO codes of regions where your phone number can be located

Comment: Thanks @0x60 for sharing it. This seems to be a possible solution but in theory there can many valid numbers. I am wondering if this is the only solution or is there a better way to approach it...